# Change complete HTML Content using javascript (Without Distorting CSS/Img files)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to change the visible HTML Text of a webpage using javascript.

Code:

```
function changeHTMLContent() {
    var server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
    var oldHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

    $.post(server_url + "/changeHTMLDoc/",
    { input_html: oldHTML,},
    function(response) {
        var resp = JSON.stringify(response);
        resp = resp.substring(1, resp.length - 1);

        var jObj = JSON.parse(resp);
        var oldText = jObj.oldText;
        var newText = jObj.newText;

        alert(newText);
        var newHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        for (var i = 0; i < oldText.length; i++) {
            newHTML = newHTML.replace(/oldText[i]/g, newText[i]);
        }
        alert(newHTML);
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = newHTML;
    });
}
```

`alert(newText)` shows the correct Text Change(which is desired one). `alert(newHTML)` is the same as `OldHTML`. (Though It should get changed from the for loop, it doesn't seem to work.)

Update:

```
newHTML = newHTML.replace(new RegExp(oldText[i],"g"), newText[i]);
```

Used this inside for loop & it changed the oldText with the newText but css/img of the html page gets distorted with this. (All the css/img files are located inside the static folder of the project.)

Can someone please suggest how to resolve it ? 
Thanks,

Comment: document.documentElement.html= newHTML; try this

Comment: Used var newHTML = document.documentElement.html; didn't worked.

Comment: ('TypeError: newHTML is undefined' in Firefox Console)

Comment: newHTML += newHTML.replace(/oldText[i]/g, newText[i]); // try this Concatenates operator with variable. may be old value replaced with new one.

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal your answer is wrong, because newHTML will concatenate with itself in each loop of for. The error is in the regexp

Answer (score 1):

This line has an error

```
newHTML = newHTML.replace(/oldText[i]/g, newText[i]);
```

You are looking to replace exactly `"oldTexti"` by another text.

If you want to replace the string from the array oldText, you have to create a regexp each time

```
newHTML = newHTML.replace(new RegExp(oldText[i],"g"), newText[i]);
```

- `/oldText[i]/g` is : find string that look likes `"oldTexti"` in
  global
- `new RegExp(oldText[i],"g")` is : find string in the array
  `oldText` at index `i` in global (g)

Comment: Okay. This is trying to change the oldText with newText but the css/imgs etc. are getting distorted with this. Is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: Use `document.body` (`<body>` tag) instead of `document.documentElement` (`<html>` tag)

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: (I am trying to change only the visible Text of an html page. & nothing else. oldText[] contains list of visible Texts only. newText[] contains the replacement texts.)

Comment: @Naveen, he means that you can get the content of the entire webpage using the `document.body` object too.

Instead of `document.documentElement.innerHTML = newHTML`, use `document.body.innerHTML = newHTML`.

`document.documentElement` gives you access to the entire page, the `<html>` tag. `document.body` gives you access to the visible content of the page, that is only the `<body>` tag, which I believe is what you need.

Comment: @Naveen 
The css is linked to from inside `<head>` tag. You need `document.body` to target only the body tag.

Comment: @JayantBhawal, Tried document.body.innerHTML = newHTML. This too replaces the HTML content but the css/imgs gets distorted. Can it be avoided ?

Comment: @Naveen, do the tags have any inline styles? And how exactly are the images included? Is there a plunkr or jsbin or anything for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102196/discussion-between-jayant-bhawal-and-naveen).

Comment: It is an HTML page, it can have any style(inside tags too). All the images are there in a static folder of the project & the images are loaded from this static folder. Not sure about plunkr/jsbin thing.

Comment: @ArnaudGueras Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Give us a better example of what you are trying to do
- an original html page
- a result of your ajax request
etc, etc...
It's better if you put all of them into plunkr

Comment: I am trying to change the visible text of this html page to different Text. Ajax Request sends back the visible text strings, oldText[](of the same HTML page) & replacement text strings, newText[]. In the javascript, I am trying to replace the oldText[] with the newText[] without distorting the css/img.

Comment: @ArnaudGueras Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: You don't answer to my question because you don't give us the result of AJAX 
And what do you want exactly to do ?

Comment: oldText[] = ["Coolest City", "Favorite Place"]. newText[] = ["coolest city", "favorite place"]. The Ajax call just extract "Coolest City" & "Favorite Place" from the given HTML Page, store it in oldText[], finds newText[](lower case characters) and returns both. I just want to replace the oldHTML visible strings(oldText[]) by newHTML Strings(newText[]) in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `html` by id.

```
var newText = jObj.newText;
document.getElementById('your_id').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('your_id').innerHTML = newText;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Complete visible HTML text content needs to be changed. It would be a very tideous task to change every text by using it's id.

Comment: Can you share the original HTML document?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna HTML File: plnkr.co/edit/7O3GdH7YcXn5Hu0NbYqB?p=catalogue